# No package name found in android manifest

Tags: react-native, package, azure-pipelines, npm-install, react-native-image-picker

Failed to build the app: No package name found.

`/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

The package name is missing in `AndroidManifest` file after `npm/pod install` to solve this issue, I have manually added the package name locally but the build gets failed in the pipeline.

**Steps to reproduce**

- npm install
- pod install

**Configuration**

- "react-native": "0.70.5",
- "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",

Please help me to solve this issue, let me know if any additional info is required.

**FYI**

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 809: unexpected token at 'info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

from /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Podfile:20
  target 'Proxus' do
  config = use_native_modules!

The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1

The 'pod' command failed with error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: similar problem here this week! Found any solution? I dont want to upgrade

Comment: @VictorioMolina yes downgrading the version to`5.4.0` worked for me .